# Changing behavior of cd linux command

Tags: bash

Please, how can i modify the behavior of `cd` command without change of `$HOME` ?

```
$ pwd                                                                                     
 /home/alice                                                                               
$ echo $HOME                                                                              
 /home/alice                                                                               
$ HOME=/home/alice/Music/                                                                 
$ cd                                                                                      
$ pwd                                                                                     
 /home/alice/Music
```

Comment: when i use cd without parameters , i will be the /tmp repository .

Comment: IMHO you have better define an alias: `alias cdt='cd /tmp'`. Changing the behavior of such basic commands is fraught with peril.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/alice
$ cd /home/alice/Music/
$ pwd
/home/alice/Music
$ HOME=/tmp
$ cd
$ pwd
/tmp
```

Comment: when i use cd without parameters , i will be the /tmp repository   can i use commands : env, printenv ?

Comment: Only if HOME=/tmp.   But as I've shown, you should use cd with a parameter.

Comment: I finally understood, you will not be in the /tmp directory, but you want to be there.  I've edited my answer accordingly.